# Как создать онлайн FTP сервер?

Tags: ftp, сервер

Создал локальный ФТП сервер, но сейчас хочу создать онлайн. У меня есть под рукой Windows Server PC. Возможно такое создавать и как? Жду ваших инструкций и советов

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен белый ip, который будет виден из интернета, далее "посадить" ftp-сервер на интерфей который смотрит в инет.